# How to get origin file from nginx cache

Tags: nginx, caching

How to get origin file from nginx cache ?

you can get cached file on the pwd, such as `/www/server/nginx/proxy_cache_dir`

nginx version

```c
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.15.10
```

`cat cached file`

```c
MD5hash
KEY: http://domain/request_uri/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Tengine
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 12379
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 14:13:09 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
x-oss-request-id: 5D4C2DF59563BC5E816932BF
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "19A6B640E83F8475B59CD1C8213C3C1C"
Last-Modified: Sun, 28 Jul 2019 15:47:50 GMT
x-oss-object-type: Normal
x-oss-hash-crc64ecma: 7799365534687729124
x-oss-storage-class: Standard
Content-MD5: Gaa2QOg/hHW1nNHIITw8HA==
x-oss-server-time: 1
Ali-Swift-Global-Savetime: 1565273589
Via: cache1.l2cn1821[53,200-0,M], cache19.l2cn1821[63,0], cache5.cn369[123,200-0,M], cache9.cn369[125,0]
Age: 0
X-Cache: MISS TCP_MISS dirn:-2:-2
X-Swift-SaveTime: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 14:13:09 GMT
X-Swift-CacheTime: 3600
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
EagleId: 01c1bcd115652735896705467e

!function(e){var t={};function n(s){if(t[s])return t[s].exports;var r=t[s]={i:s,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[s].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,n),r.l=!0,r.exports}n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,s){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:s})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var s=Object.create(null);if(n.r
........large js file....
```

So, how to get js file from nginx cached file ?